# Request admin privileges to edit system files

Tags: c#, privileges, sharpziplib

New to C#, I'm developing a windows form application inside visual studio. The app uses [ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/) library to update a zip's content.

When the zip file is inside a non system partition, say like `D:\myzip.zip` the files gets updated correctly. But, if the zip is in the system partition, `C:\myzip.zip` the app returns an error; `Could not find file C:\myzip.zip` even though the file is there!

This has to do with admin privileges because when I run the app as administrator it works.

The question is; how could I enable those privileges by default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force my .NET App to run as administrator on Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7)

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add app manifest to exact your app to run as administrator ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx)).

Add the following code to your manifest file:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Adding app manifest step by step:

1. Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer.
2. Click *Add New Item*.
3. Find and select *Application Manifest File*:

[image]

Edit app manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
      <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
          <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">       
            <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
          </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
      </trustInfo>

      <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
        <application>    
        </application>
      </compatibility>
    </asmv1:assembly>
```

Comment: I already tried that but the when I run the release app, it doesn't ask for admin privileges by default; I mean, without doing right-click run as admin..

Comment: @numediaweb I added step by step how add app manifest to your app. Check this out.

Comment: I already did that by updating `app.manifest` in solution explorer.. but somehow after playing with the project settings.. now it works!

Answer (score -1):

you want to enable this by default on you'r computer only right? 
because on other computer you can't, this what security all about

Comment: I want that the app when run on other computers (and mine included) asks for admin privileges so it can write to files inside, say `C:\Program Files (x86)\..`

Comment: Clarification questions should be as comments to the initial question and not as answers, downvoted